# GDAL_Translate not compressing when NoData value is set

Tags: qgis, postgis, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I am trying to compress a .TIF file using GDAL_Translate or GDAL_Warp. My Raster is 32mb to start with. When I use GDAL_Translate with the COMPRESS=PACKBITS option, it compresses to 1.9mb.

However if I now set the NoData value to -1 along with the COMPRESS=PACKBITS option my raster does not compress. Does anyone know what my be causing this? I have tried a number of - and + NoData values with the same result.

Comment: What sort of tiff it is? Take gdalinfo report and show us what it tells about the bands.

Comment: Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Size is 2250, 3450
Coordinate System is:
Origin = (681200.000000000000000,8226800.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (20.000000000000000,-20.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=IMAGINE TIFF Support
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=PACKBITS
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Band 1 Block=512x512 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray